# Node js require json using variable (var)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to require `./../bin/<variable>.json`. So I make a var as `var (reqLink = "'./../bin/"+lanID+".json'")` and pass to `(var engJason = require(reqLink))` but it didn't work. But it does work with a relative path like this `(var engJason = require('./../bin/eng.json');)`

```
var reqLink = "'./../bin/"+lanID+".json'";
var engJason = require(reqLink);

//Not working ||error Cannot find module ''./../bin/eng.json''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the extra single quotes:

`"'./../bin/"+lanID+".json'"` => `"./../bin/" + lanID + ".json"`

Comment: Thank you very much. Quick and helpful